# Composition of function

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions

I have these two functions and I have to do Jacobi matrix of their composition $h\circ c$.

$h\left(r,\phi\right)=\begin{pmatrix} rcos\phi \\ rsin\phi \\ r \end{pmatrix} $

$c\left(t\right)=\begin{pmatrix} e^{t} \\ e^{-t}  \end{pmatrix}  $

First I tried to do their composition, but I am confused of the way that g is given here (like vector). So my idea is that $r=e^{t}
 $ and $\phi=e^{-t}$. And just to put it in h. Is that correct?

If yes, then to take derivatives of all three components of h? And what after that. How to put h in this form in Jacobi matrix?

I would be very thankful if someone could tell me is my idea good or not and give me some advice or do this example.

Answer (score 1):

Your ideas are correct. After you get $h$ just differentiate each entry of $h$ to get $J$ which in this case is a $3\times1$ matrix.$$
h\circ c(t)=h(e^t,e^{-t})=\begin{bmatrix}e^t\cos e^{-t}\\e^t\sin e^{-t}\\e^{t}\end{bmatrix}\\
\implies J(t)=\begin{bmatrix}e^t\cos e^{-t}+\sin e^{-t}\\e^t\sin e^{-t}-\cos e^{-t}\\e^{t}\end{bmatrix}
$$